# Paperclip set :extension to mp3 if no extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I'm working on a rails 3 app that uses paperclip to save audio files to Amazon S3. I'm saving lots of mp3 files that are being transferred from a url, but they are being transferred without an extension. I know these files are mp3 files, but in paperclip they do not have an extension. How can I set the extension to mp3 if there is no extension provided?

```
    has_attached_file :audio,
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/aws.yml",
    :hash_secret => 'secret',
    :hash_data => ':class/:attachment/:id',
    :path           => ':rails_env/:class/:id/:style/:hash.:extension'

def transfer_to_s3
    io = open(URI.parse(recording_url + '.mp3'))        
    self.audio = io
    self.save
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess but try this :..

Change:

```
has_attached_file :photo, :url => "/:class/:attachment/:id/:style_:basename.:extension"
```

To:

```
has_attached_file :photo, :url => lambda { |attachment| { :url => (attachment.match(/mp3/).nil? ? "/:class/:attachment/:id/:style_:basename.mp3" : "/:class/:attachment/:id/:style_:basename.:extension") }
```

Just a wild idea. There might be some syntactical damage in there, but maybe it'll push you in the right direction. Sorry :D

You could also do a after_save `match` and `gsub` combo.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your files are not being saved as .mp3 is because you are using **open-uri**. Change the save code to:

```
self.audio = URI.parse(recording_url)
self.save
```

This should solve your problem.

The reason this occurs is because open-uri creates a tempfile without an extension and that gets provided to Paperclip.

[Original Article](http://dev.mensfeld.pl/2013/12/rails-paperclip-open-uri-downloading-files-from-the-internet-and-saving-them-with-paperclip/)

Hope this helps.